# Why does adding ORDER BY cause my MySQL query to get stuck with a Left Join?

Tags: sql, mysql

how to select table one by condition in table 2 with foreign key in table 1 and order by asc ?

hi guys, Im trying to make query like this

```sql
SELECT chapters.* FROM giangthe.chapters
Left join giangthe.stories
  on chapters.story_id = stories.id
where stories.host = 'faloo' and complete_free = 1
order by chapters.id asc;
```

everything work fine but when i put order by chapters.id acs, it get stuck, i make order because i want go get one by one part of query because it very large query. how should i make it better ? thanks guys

Comment: What do you mean by _"it get stuck"_? Also, what is the point of the `LEFT JOIN` if you're not selecting anything from the joined table?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, either. Is the query too slow and you are looking for optimization? Or what else? And `where stories.host = 'faloo'` dismisses all outer joined rows (the host of which is null by definition), so your outer join becomes an inner join thus. Which table does the `complete_free` column belong to?

Comment: it get stuck i mean, the fetch get infinity loading and that seem not normal

Comment: Please add the table definitions as text together with a note of the populations.

Comment: We are stuck, too. You have been asked what the outer join is supposed to be for, but you haven't answered. You have been asked which table the complete_free column resides in, but you haven't answered. Anyway, you are right, this query shouldn't take that long. What indexes do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this query?

```
SELECT chapters.*
FROM giangthe.stories
LEFT JOIN giangthe.chapters 
   ON chapters.story_id = stories.id
WHERE stories.host = 'faloo' 
   AND stories.complete_free = 1
ORDER BY chapters.id ASC;
```

We are using the `stories` table to filter the data, so it can be our based table.

Also, it's possible to optimize the performance if you are missing indexes that can improve how data is read by your current query. In order to offer you such, you need to share the tables structure first.

Very shortly, when a table has more columns that contains large amount of data, you need to read all the data in order to get just particular information. If you have a covering index, you may read only the needed data.

Comment: it still the same i dont know why bro, i doing with workbench, there is something wrong with the fetching process, it show me 0/0 sec, seem not normal, but when i delete order by then everything work fine idk